# Crystal Report formula if-else statement Date condition

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I would like to ask about how to use if-else statement in the crystal report formula.

I want something like

```
If Date = "01/01/1900" Then 
//Display "-" 
Else 
//Display Date
```

But i always faced that the field is require number, currency and date error.
I am still new with crystal report. Hope u guys can guide me about this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
if  totext((Date(Year(YourDateField), Month(YourDateField), Day(YourDateField))),'dd/MM/yyyy') ="01/01/1900" then
"-" 
else 
totext((Date(Year(YourDateField), Month(YourDateField), Day(YourDateField))),'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Comment: Thx! Why it is necessary to use ToText??

Comment: because you must use the same type of data in the entire formula, so if you want to use text  after "then" and "else" you must use text also in the condition